# GetDesignDocuments from golang SDK

Tags: pointers, go, sdk, couchbase

I would like to retrieve all Design Documents of given bucket.
So I prepared short code

```
err := cbSrc.Connect()
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err.Error())
    os.Exit(2)
}

bm := cbSrc.Bucket.Manager(username, password)

dds, err := bm.GetDesignDocuments()
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err.Error())
    os.Exit(3)
}

log.Printf("%#v\n", dds)

for ind := range dds {
    fmt.Println(dds[ind].Name)
}
```

and I'm always receiving slice of pointers with correct length, but the addresses of the pointers is always the same

```
[]*gocb.DesignDocument{(*gocb.DesignDocument)(0xc82011eb50), (*gocb.DesignDocument)(0xc82011eb50), (*gocb.DesignDocument)(0xc82011eb50)}
```

So basically, I receive 3 times the third design model.
And for range statement gives me 3 times the same value

Comment: Write a small test that inserts design documents into a new bucket and then retrieves them. Does that work? If not, post that code and more details.

Comment: It's clear from your question that your code isn't working, but there's not enough information to diagnose why. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I just want to list the Design Documents